# Overloading Typecasts C++ , How it works?

Tags: c++, overloading, typecast-operator

I was going through the below link to understand the topic.
[Over Loading Typecasts C++](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/)

```
class Cents
{
private:
    int m_nCents;
public:
    Cents(int nCents=0)
    {
        m_nCents = nCents;
    }

    // Overloaded int cast
    operator int() { return m_nCents; }

    int GetCents() { return m_nCents; }
    void SetCents(int nCents) { m_nCents = nCents; }
};
```

Now in our example, we call PrintInt() like this:

```
int main()
{
    Cents cCents(7);
    PrintInt(cCents); // print 7

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot understand How PrintInt(cCents) maps to to printing 7 and using the overloaded int operator.

Comment: The article you link to explains exactly what's going on. What part of it didn't you understand?

Comment: Yes, actually the article explains very well...

Comment: From the linked article: "The compiler will first note that PrintInt takes an integer parameter. Then it will note that cCents is not an int. Finally, it will look to see if we’ve provided a way to convert a Cents into an int. Since we have, it will call our operator int() function, which returns an int, and the returned int will be passed to PrintInt()." That explains *exactly* what's happening.

Comment: No i understood !! thanks a lot all!!

Comment: Sigh. Too much sloppy terminology. Despite its title, that article isn't about overloading typecasts. It's about providing a user-defined conversion operator. That conversion operator can be used for implicit conversions **and** for explicit conversions (i.e., typecasts).

Answer (score 2):

Overloading int cast means when a `Cents` variable is casted to int, it'll return the `m_nCents`

```
// Overloaded int cast
operator int() { return m_nCents; }
```